# Qemu-Arm file access?

Tags: c, qemu

I am attempting to set up an arm debug environment for a project. One of the primary code functions required for the project is to load a binary file into memory (6mb).

I have installed qemu-arm on ubuntu linux 12.04, compiled GDB with target set to arm. I am attempting to compile the following test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
int fd = open("files/test.txt", O_RDONLY);
printf("File handle: %i ", fd);
perror(NULL);
return 0
}
```

Command line:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -static -no-stack-protector -g test.c -o test;qemu-arm  ./test
```

Output:

```
File handle: -1 No such file or directory
```

Seems like it can't find the file, I believe this to be because QEMU doesn't have access to it... I am not very experienced with QEMU but given my prior experience with virtual machines I would guess this to be the case.

Can anyone help clear this up?

EDIT:
Wow, I solved it, seems I had a typo in my code and the file path was incorrect. Fixed now... should I just close it? my question is invalid since it was a dumb typo. Typo not present in code I posted.

Comment: You don't you query `errno` and see what exactly prevented the program from opening the file? just write `perror(NULL);` right after the `fd = open(...` line.

Comment: Will try and edit in a moment. My c code is very weak I didnt know to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you found the solution to your problem by fixing a typo I thought I would address this question that you asked:

> Seems like it can't find the file, I believe this to be because QEMU
>   doesn't have access to it... I am not very experienced with QEMU but
>   given my prior experience with virtual machines I would guess this to
>   be the case.

QEMU has two modes of operation.  One is as a full-system emulator which is similar to other VMs that you may be familiar with.

The other mode is as a user-mode emulator, and that is what you are using.  In this mode QEMU translates the **user-mode** instructions from one ISA to another.  In your case it is translating ARM instructions to x86 instructions.  However, when handling system calls the emulator executes them directly in the host OS.  So this is why QEMU is able to access the local file system just like any other process you ran would be able to.